# Python Consumer-Producer. Producer waits for the consumer to consume

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to have 2 tasks. One is the producer and the other is the consumer. The producer must wait for the consumer to consume the data in order to generate new. The execution flow must be: fpga, bbb, fpga, bbb, fpga, bbb, fpga, bbb, fpga, bbb.....
When i have a big sleeping time for the producer everyting works fine, but when the sleep time is small im having a deadlock. ¿Does anyone know why? My code:

```
class fpga (threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self,condition,data):
                    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                    self.name='fpga'
                    self.condition=condition
                    self.data=data
                    self.sleepTime=1.0/(300.0*18.0) 
                    self.count=0
            def run(self):
                    while True:
                            newData='YxxY'
                            self.condition.acquire()
                            self.condition.notify()
                            self.condition.wait()
                            self.condition.release()

                            time.sleep(self.sleepTime) #sleep some time
                            print 'fpga'

    class bbb (threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self,condition,data):
                    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                    self.name='bbb'
                    self.condition=condition
                    self.data=data
            def run (self):
                    while True:
                            self.condition.acquire()
                            self.condition.wait()
                            self.condition.notify()
                            self.condition.release()
                            print 'bbb'
    if __name__=='__main__':
            dataFpga=[]     
            dataFromFpgaCondition=threading.Condition()     
            threadfpga=fpga(dataFromFpgaCondition,dataFpga)
            threadBbb=bbb(dataFromFpgaCondition,dataFpga)
            threadBbb.start()
            threadfpga.start()
            threadBbb.join()
            threadfpga.join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a race in your code.

Your producer, `fpga`, Needs to do the following:

1. `acquire` the `condition` lock
2. Make some new data available (not clear how that happens in your example code)
3. `notify` the other thread
4. `release` the `condition` lock

The consumer, `bbb`, needs to do the following:

1. `acquire` the `condition` lock
2. `wait` to be notified that data is available (important: this releases the lock)
3. Do something with the data
4. `notify` the producer that it's done processing
5. `release` the `condition` lock

Your consumer is doing exactly the steps listed above:

```
self.condition.acquire()  # Step 1
self.condition.wait()  # Step 2
self.condition.notify()  # Step 4 (step 3 is left out here, but its not important)
self.condition.release() # Step 5
```

However, your producer is not following the steps:

```
self.condition.acquire() # Step 1
self.condition.notify() # Step 2
self.condition.wait() # This isn't a step! And we're releasing the lock when we do it!
self.condition.release() # Step 4 (no step 3 again, but that's ok)
```

You have a needless `wait` call immediately after calling `notify`. This introduces a race condition. You can end up with this:

```
bbb.condition.acquire()
bbb.condition.wait() # This releases the lock and then blocks, waiting to be notified
fpa.condition.acquire()
fpga.condition.notify()
fpga.condition.wait() # bbb acquires the lock right after this, because it's in wait()
bbb.condition.notify()
bbb.condition.release() # fpga.wait() now completes
fpga.condition.release() # Ok, both threads just called release. Now it's race.
fpga.condition.acquire() # The producer won the race. This is bad.
fpga.condition.notify()
fpga.condition.wait() # Releases the lock and waits
bbb.condition.acquire()
bbb.condition.wait() # No they're both waiting, and you're deadlocked.
```

You avoid this by adding the `sleep` call, because once we get to the race point, the producer pauses in the `sleep`, which will let the consumer win. Without the sleep, or with a very short sleep, the producer can win.

The fix is just to remove the call to `self.condition.wait()` in the producer.

Comment: Make some new data available (not clear how that happens in your example code): I just omited that part cause its not relevant. Thx works fine, your answer helped me understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that both threads `wait` for the other, for example the following schedule

```
fpga.acquire
fpga.notify
fpga.wait
bbb.acquire
bbb.wait
```

is possible and leads to a deadlock very quickly.

Your method does not work because `notify` is not "remembered", if there is no waiting thread at the time a `notify` is executed, the notification is lost.